# Content-Security-Policy error in JHipster generated Angular application

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a JHispter generated application. I removed `useHash` property in RouterModule:

```
imports: [
    ...,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
],
```

After I navigate to a view and hit refresh, I get following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".

In an ordinary angular-cli generated application, the view is displayed without any errors when you hit refresh.

Why Content-Security-Policy error is encountered in JHipster generated application when you disable `useHash`?

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? I have a similar issue after upgrading from Angular 4.x to 5.0.0

Comment: I am using Angular 4

Comment: did you find a solution, i have same problem now with version 6.1.2 which also does not have the hash (by default now)

Comment: in SecurityConfiguration.java you can set the content security policy rules